# How to rank in r for a given condition?

Tags: r, rank

I have a vector

```
x<-c(1,5,0.4,1.3,0.2,0.6)
```

I want to rank x in decreasing order only for the values that are greater than 1.
I don't to change the x vector by removing values that are less than 1.

My desired output is like

```
rank=c(3,1,Null,2,Null,Null)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: One-liner `replace(NA_real_, x >= 1, rank(-x[x >= 1]))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
x <- c(1,5,0.4,1.3,0.2,0.6)
temp <- x
temp[temp < 1] <- NA
rank(-temp, na.last = "keep") # -temp so that the decreasing order is used

# [1]  3  1 NA  2 NA NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Etienne!!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
rnk <- rep(NA, length(x))
w <- which(x>=1)
rnk[w] <- rank(-x[w])

#[1]  3  1 NA  2 NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,5,0.4,1.3,0.2,0.6))

library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
   mutate(filtered = ifelse(x<1, NA, x)) %>%
   mutate(rank = rank(-filtered, na.last = "keep"))
df

    x filtered rank
1 1.0      1.0    3
2 5.0      5.0    1
3 0.4       NA   NA
4 1.3      1.3    2
5 0.2       NA   NA
6 0.6       NA   NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much mpschramm :)